# SQL Count no result if condition is 0

Tags: sql, join

Hi my code is right about showing the right result wherein count in another table with same value of column

My Database:

Clientgroup table

```
id | clientgroup_name | clientgroup_color
10   Business Customer  green
11   Super VIP          red
12   Ultimate VIP       pink
```

Client List Table:

```
id | name   | group_id 
1    John      10
2    Mark      10
3    Paul      12
4    Nico      12
```

My code:

```
SELECT Count(*) as Count,clientgroup_table.clientgroup_name,clientgroup_table.clientgroup_color FROM clientgroup_table, client_list WHERE client_list.group_id = clientgroup_table.id GROUP BY clientgroup_table.clientgroup_name
```

My result:

```
Count | clientgroup_name | clientgroup_color
2       Business Customer   green
2       Ultimate VIP        pink
```

**My desired result:**

```
Count | clientgroup_name | clientgroup_color
2       Business Customer   green
2       Ultimate VIP        pink
0       SUPER VIP           red
```

I want to show 0 even there's no row equal to it

Is it possible?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your current query has two problems which are giving you the wrong output.  First, you are using an implicit inner join which is discarding records from the client group table which do not match.  Instead, you should be using a `LEFT JOIN`.  Second, you are counting with `COUNT(*)` which will give a false count of one for records on the left which do not match anything on the right.  Instead, use `COUNT(some column from the right)`.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(t2.group_id) AS Count,   -- returns 0 if t2.group_id is NULL
    t1.clientgroup_name,
    t1.clientgroup_color
FROM clientgroup_table t1
LEFT JOIN client_list t2
    ON t2.group_id = t1.id
GROUP BY
    t1.clientgroup_name,
    t1.clientgroup_color
ORDER BY
    Count DESC,
    t1.clientgroup_name;
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks for this.
But its resulting into 1 instead of 0
WHY?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the left join operation to do this to include the other rows that don't have any client.
Try this query:

```
SELECT 
  Count(*) as Count,
  clientgroup_table.clientgroup_name,
  clientgroup_table.clientgroup_color 
FROM clientgroup_table left join client_list 
  on client_list.group_id = clientgroup_table.id 
GROUP BY clientgroup_table.clientgroup_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join in this case :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Count, clientgroup_name,clientgroup_color FROM client_group 
cg LEFT JOIN client_list cl ON cg.id=cl.group_id GROUP BY 
cg.clientgroup_name,cg.clientgroup_color
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null
drop table #t1
CREATE TABLE #t1
    ([id] int, [clientgroup_name] varchar(17), [clientgroup_color] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO #t1
    ([id], [clientgroup_name], [clientgroup_color])
VALUES
    (10, 'Business Customer', 'green'),
    (11, 'Super VIP', 'red'),
    (12, 'Ultimate VIP', 'pink')
;


if object_id('tempdb..#t2') is not null
drop table #t2
CREATE TABLE #t2
    ([id] int, [name] varchar(4), [group_id] int)
;

INSERT INTO #t2
    ([id], [name], [group_id])
VALUES
    (1, 'John', 10),
    (2, 'Mark', 10),
    (3, 'Paul', 12),
    (4, 'Nico', 12)
;

select count(r.group_id) count,t.clientgroup_name,t.clientgroup_color from #t1 t left join #t2 r on r.group_id=t.id
group by t.clientgroup_name,t.clientgroup_color
```